# How to connect a QML signal to a C++ slot using the New Qt signals and slots syntax?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Sorry if this is a newbie question.
This is the old syntax:

```
QObject::connect("QQuickWindow* cast of my QML engine", SIGNAL(qmlsignal()), "cppClass* object name", SLOT(doSomething()));
```

But when I use the new syntax:

```
QObject::connect("QQuickWindow* cast of my QML engine", &QQuickWindow::???!!!, "cppClass* object name", &CppClass::doSomething);
```

The casting of QML engine to QQuickWindow* won't show me the signals/functions defined in QML, so I don't know how to connect them (please don't laugh :D)

How should I use the new syntax if I want to connect QML and C++ signals/slots? Since my current approach is clearly wrong. Is it even possible to use the new syntax for this?

Comment: The C++ shouldn't be aware of your QML code; it's better to do it the other way around: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-bestpractices.html#exposing-data-from-c-to-qml

Comment: @Mitch AFAIK your proposed method CAN be used for connecting a cpp signal to a qml slot, BUT it cannot be used to connect a qml signal to a cpp slot which we want to run in another thread. Writing the connection in QML, the QML will directly run the slot from the main thread (it will not be multi-threaded). Is there any way for the called function to be run in another thread? If so, can you please say how or provide an example?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if that's true. Have you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads? Qt::AutoConnection is the default and is thread-aware. As a side note, you didn't mention threads in your question - if you're newer to Qt it's probably better to state what you're trying to achieve at a high level, then explain what you've tried and why it didn't work. That way you can avoid leaving out information but also possibly get better alternative solutions.

Comment: New syntax has been introduced due to inherent type unsafety of the old one. So you couldn't be sure that the connection is valid until the code gets executed. It also would not allow to connect to the freshly added anonymous functions (lambda). So the new syntax is good when you have types known at the compile time and/or using lambdas. When your connection is dynamic by its nature (QML) you should just use the old syntax, because it is where it shines (well, no much to choose from anyway).

Comment: @OP if your cpp object (CO) lives in Thread 2 (T2) and you pass it to QML and in QML you connect some QML signal to the CO's slot then, when you emit the QML signal, the CO`s slot will be executed in T2. (Disclaimer: I don't remember if it is possible to connect a QML signal to CO's slot in QML)

Comment: @Mitch Somewhere in the QML docs I read that Qt::DirectConnection is used.